# How to identify where an identifier is defined to refactor in delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, refactoring, delphi-7

I am trying to refactor some delphi 7 code. One of the procedures I'd like to move uses a data type called TLVColumn (appears to be a TListView column header). However, if I move the method, I get an undeclared identifier error, presumedly because I didn't copy the import which defines TLVColumn to the new unit. The unit I'm moving this method from has over 7000 lines of code and over 50 uses classes listed. Is there any more efficient way than trial and error of copying random imports to identify which import is required for a particular class? (especially imports that are from Delphi libraries and not from my own codebase...)

Comment: (Install GExpert and) run a grep search over all project units and if necessary on the root of all your source folders. If you search for `TLVColumn = class(` you should find the declaration pretty quickly.

Comment: What about using ctrl + click over the identifier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before to move the procedure just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + left click over the identifier and the IDE will navigate to the unit where is declarated.

Comment: Hmmm, that works for some of them, the ones that are in my codebase. The ones from Delphi libraries it doesn't seem to work on. But "Browse Symbol at Cursor" in the right click menu seems to be working on the others.